# How to send an email alert when a linux service has stopped?

Tags: linux, systemd

I have Systemd service that is supposed to be running all the time. I would like to get alerted by email in case the service has stopped? What is the best way to do it in linux?

Comment: We use Naemon to monitor our systems. It’s easy to configure it to send an email if a service is down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ExecStopPost` setting in your service configuration, as documented in [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) to send an email whenever the service stops. If you don't want to receive an email when the service exits cleanly, you can use the `SERVICE_RESULT` environment variable (documented in [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)) in the script sending the email.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a short bash script that checks the status of the service and pushes a notification if it is not running. For pushing notifications you can use [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) which is pretty easy to integrate with a bash script after generating security keys.
Your bash script can be added to the `crontab` for periodic execution say every 5 minutes(basically whatever period you want).